# How to troubleshoot "CancellationTokenSource has been disposed" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am seeing a number of these errors in the logs for a .NET Core 2.2.x web app:

```
Connection ID ""13546832108852449106"", Request ID ""80018f57-0407-bc00-b63f-84710c7967bb"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

System.ObjectDisposedException: The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed.     
at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ThrowObjectDisposedException()     
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.<>c__DisplayClass314_0.<AbortIO>b__0(Object t)
```

As you can see, the error occurs in the .net core framework rather than my code.

I looked up the specific Request Id mentioned in the error and it seems to have processed just fine.  The error appears in the log about a second after the request has processed and returned data.  I also checked the Event Viewer and there wasn't anything suspicious around the time frame of the error.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

The Windows 2016 server has .NET Core 2.2.6 runtime installed.

Comment: I found issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4422). It seems it will be addressed in 3.0 release.

Comment: @dropoutcoder It says it was fixed by merging [#9389](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/9389) by into master, which I am assuming is v3.0.  They've mentioned that it was going to be fixed for 2.2.x, but as of yet nothing.